# What is the BCEL Instruction to read my desired code block

Tags: java, bytecode, call-graph, bcel

I am developing a call method using Bcel.But i couldn't reach getTweets function.It stops after ActionListener.What is the instruction for it?

**Here is how i read instructions:**

```
for (InstructionHandle ih = mg.getInstructionList().getStart(); 
                ih != null; ih = ih.getNext()) {
            Instruction i = ih.getInstruction();

            if (!visitInstruction(i))
                i.accept(this);
        }
```

**here is code which i read with BCEL:**

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                            JTextArea textArea = new **JTextArea(getTweets("#XXX"));**                           
                            textArea.setLineWrap(true);  
                            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                            textArea.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);


                            JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                            jScrollPane1.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jScrollPane1, "Tweets",  
                                    JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);


                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Which method are you trying to read? Because actionPerformed is going to be in a different class than the outer code.

Comment: i am trying to read main method.